# cache keys $cid naming practices (cache_set and cache_get)

Tags: caching

For using cache_get and cache_set

According to [this comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/19279#comment-19279)

> The convention seems to be to use colons to create a sort of
>   namespacing. So your module may want to do something like $cid =
>   'mymodule:mything:50';

so:

- is ':' the recommended delimiter?
- should the module name go first? (seems sensible)?
- are there characters to avoid?
- are there other considerations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **is ':' the recommended delimiter?** I haven't heard that `:` is recommended over anything else, but since it's definitely used all over core, it would make a lot of sense. All cache backends that work with Drupal will be handling `:` well.
2. **should the module name go first? (seems sensible)?**
   Yes, this is general practice, not just cache keys.
3. **are there characters to avoid?**
   None that I've heard of. In general, in 2013, if any system doesn't properly handle any character in a string properly, I would find really bad to be honest. With that said, we'll always be dealing with one form or another of legacy software. So stick to a-z, numbers and `:` if you're feeling risk averse.
4. **are there other considerations?**
   Can't immediately think of any.

Comment: thanks! re 4. - one factor is that cache clearing is done on the initial part of the key, so worth considering any cache clearing functionality that you may need.